# array typescript remove and put back an element to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter

i have a problem with an array i'm using angular typescript

i have an array whit 5 elements , and i have 4 use cases, in the 4 case i need to remove the arr.[3] of the array in the other 1,2,3 cases i need the arr[3] element

```
arr: [] = [1,2,3,4,5];

switch (event) {

            case 1:
                console.log(arr); // 1,2,3,4,5
                break;
            case 2:
                console.log(arr); // 1,2,3,4,5
                break;
            case 3:
                console.log(arr); // 1,2,3,4,5
                break;
            case 4:
                const arrIndex = this.arr[3];
                this.arr = this.arr.filter(function(item){
                    return item !== arrIndex
                }); 
                console.log(arr); // 1,2,3,5
                break;


}
```

after case 4 i delete whit filter the arr[3] how can i put back the arr[3] element?

Comment: Do you want to modify the array in place in order to add the element again, or do you want a new array that places back the element? Also, is the element supposed to be back in its original position?

Comment: i want to modify the array in place in order to add the element again

Comment: Then you can just use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: i had a wrong i want a new array that places back the element

Comment: Are you looking for an "undo" functionality?

Comment: yes "Are you looking for an "undo" functionality?"

Answer (score 0):

In order to create an array with a new element inserted at an arbitrary position in it, your easiest choice is combining [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat).

1. Make an array of everything *before* the insert point and an array of everything *after*.
2. Create an array that combines the starting array, the item, and the end array.

```js
function createArrayAndAdd(sourceArray, newItem, indexToInsert) {
  const start = sourceArray.slice(0, indexToInsert);
  const end = sourceArray.slice(indexToInsert);
  
  return [].concat(start, newItem, end);
}

const originalArray = [ 
  { id: 1, name: "Alice" }, 
  { id: 2, name: "Bob" }, 
  { id: 4, name: "David" }
]

const elementToAdd = { id: 3, name: "Carol" };
const insertAt = 2;

console.log("result: ", createArrayAndAdd(originalArray, elementToAdd, insertAt));

console.log("original is unmodified", originalArray)
```

Alternatively, you can create a copy of the array and modify that copy with [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
function createArrayAndAdd(sourceArray, newItem, indexToInsert) {
  const result = sourceArray.slice();
  
  result.splice(indexToInsert, 0, newItem);
  
  return result;
}

const originalArray = [ 
  { id: 1, name: "Alice" }, 
  { id: 2, name: "Bob" }, 
  { id: 4, name: "David" }
]

const elementToAdd = { id: 3, name: "Carol" };
const insertAt = 2;

console.log("result: ", createArrayAndAdd(originalArray, elementToAdd, insertAt));

console.log("original is unmodified", originalArray)
```